# Python adding attachment to an e-mail from a function

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I am trying to automate sending attachments and e-mails from Python:

```
def Emailer(text, subject, recipient):
    import win32com.client as win32   
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HtmlBody = text
    mail.Display(True)
    attachment = 'C:/Users/.../file.pdf'
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)

Emailer('text', 'test', 'name@mail.com')
```

However, this does not add an attachment. The path should be correct, because when I try below, it works:

```
import win32com.client as win32
mail = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application').CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'name@mail.com'
mail.Subject = 'test'
mail.HTMLBody = 'text'

attachment  = 'C:/Users/.../file.pdf'
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
mail.Display(True)
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong with my `Emailer()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Emailer you call `MailItem.Display(True)` before you add the attachment, whereas in the "working" snippet you do so after. According to [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.display) `Display(True)` creates a modal window, it might also be a blocking call meaning `Emailer` would stop running until you close the window.

I'd suggest moving the call to `Display` to after you've added the attachment, or maybe try opening a non-modal window.

Incidentally, according to the doc linked above Display is deprecated.

Comment: Very simple solution. Thanks!